# Error Failed to load next.config.js when starting my Blitzjs App

Tags: node.js, next.js, blitz.js

I'm trying to run my blitjs app but it fails with an error from next

Trying to run blitz dev to start app, but it fails

> error Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
> Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/client/resolve-href'

Answer (score 0):

may be you should restart windows, that'll fix everything

Comment: Did not help sadly

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating Next.js, issue was newer blitzjs version.

You can do that by changing the version at `package.json` or running `npm upgrade next` at the root of your blitzjs project.

It worked for me to upgrade to version `"next": "13.5.6"`